# Find distinct values and return with one another column

Tags: c#, linq

Find distinct values from a column and return with one another column. So that I could use it in select dropdown. I am a beginner, any help would be appreciated.

index.razor: (This is how my razor page looks)

```
@page "/"
@if (result != null)
{     
     <select required bind="desc">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Search by Description</option>
        @foreach (var r in result)
        {
            <option value="@r.name">@r.desc</option>
        }
    </select>
 }


@code{

        Item[] data;

        public class Item
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string desc { get; set; }             
            public int point{ get; set; }
        }  

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    data = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Item[]>("sample-data/dataFile.json"); 
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "data ", data); // data from json shown below
  
    var result = data
   .GroupBy(item => item.name, item => item.desc)
   .Select(group => (name: group.Key, desc: group.First()))
   .ToArray();
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "result", result); // returns [{},{}]
          

 // When I use 'result' variable directly in select dropdown, it says local variable cant be used. So tried declaring result as below but nothing helped so far.
 //(string, string)[] result = new (string, string)[]();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item => $"name: {item.name}, desc: {item.kind}");
        //above console.Writeline throws error - "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type"
    }     
    
     /*foreach (var item in result)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
                above writeline(item) returns 
                (A, fragile)
                (C, hard)
            }*/
}
```

Data I receive from json:

```
 data = [
        {name: A, desc: fragile, point:70},
        {name: A, desc: sturdy, point:80},
        {name: C, desc: hard, point:100},
        {name: C, desc: soft, point:150},
```

How do I display distinct name with their respective desc, Like below:

```
 result = [
        {name: A, desc: fragile},          
        {name: C, desc: hard} 
       ]
```

So that I could use it for select dropdown. Thank you.

Comment: `A` exists with both ID 1 and 2. `C` exists with ID 3 and 4. How is the query supposed to choose which ID to show if multiples exist?

Comment: C# is a language of types. Please use C# code to show data and formats. Your `data` and `result` are meaningless in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You are, probably, looking for `GroupBy` grouping by `name`:

```
var data = new Item[] {
  new Item() {name = "A", desc = "fragile", point =  70},
  new Item() {name = "A", desc = "sturdy",  point =  80},
  new Item() {name = "C", desc = "hard",    point = 100},
  new Item() {name = "C", desc = "soft",    point = 150}, 
};
      
var result = data
  .GroupBy(item => item.name, item => item.desc)
  .Select(group => (name : group.Key, kind : group.First()))
  .ToArray(); // <- if you want to have an array
```

Let's have a look:

```
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(item => $"{item.name} : {item.kind}"));
      
Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Output:**

```
A : fragile
C : hard
```

For each `name` (`A`, `C`) I put their first corresponding `kind` (`fragile`, `hard`)

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TSZ1YO) youself

**Edit:** If you want to *loop* over `result` and format the output yourself:

```
foreach (var item in result) {
  Console.WriteLine($"name: {item.name}, desc: {item.kind}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looks promising. But I get empty list of dictionaries. result = [{},{}].

Comment: I would appreciate if you could write for the edited code above. I have changed int ID to string desc. Thank you.

Comment: Tried using desc: : group.Any() and desc: : group.First(). But I get same result that is empty.

Comment: @Tar270: OK, I see you don't have `ID` but `desc`; the idea is the same: `GroupBy` followed by some aggregate function: if we have `A : fragile` and `A : sturdy` and we keep just one `A` of two, we have to chose which `kind` (`fragile` or `sturdy`) to preserve. In my code above I preserve the very `First` ocurrence of `kind`

Comment: Thanks again. Exactly the answer I am expecting but in the format I have shown, so that I can loop thru. So that I can use those values in select dropdown as below.  eg: @foreach (var r in report)
            {
                <option value="@r.name">@r.desc</option>
            }

Comment: @Tar270: if you want to *loop* you should loop over `result`, not `report` (which is the final `string` report); see my edit

Comment: When I try the code motioned, it says "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type". As I mentioned before when I console 'result' variable as such, it returns [{},{}].  Also when I use result variable in select dropdown, it says local variable cannot be used. I am still a beginner, thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: I have edited code to add the exact razor page - to let know what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tar270: I'm sorry for the typo, it should be `Console.WriteLine($"name: {item.name}, desc: {item.kind}");`. Fiddle and answer are edited